# Is it more efficient to grep twice or use a regular expression once?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to parse a couple of 2gb+ files and want to grep on a couple of levels.

Say I want to fetch lines that contain "foo" and lines that also contain "bar".

I could do `grep foo file.log | grep bar`, but my concern is that it will be expensive running it twice.

Would it be beneficial to use something like `grep -E '(foo.*bar|bar.*foo)'` instead?

Comment: I can and will try it, but I'm curious if others had ideas and or insight. Plus, I wanted to ask my first question on SO, haha.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, is it?

Comment: grep -E '(foo|bar)' is not equivalent to your piped greps.  Do you really want foo AND bar?

Comment: won't `grep -E '(foo|bar)'` match lines that either have `foo` or `bar` not lines that have both?

Comment: Ah, right. I am aware of the regex error. I honestly didn't give it a ton of thought, was just trying to get the point accross. @Gabe, I do think this is a programming question, although I can understand why you wouldn't believe it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep -E '(foo|bar)'` will find lines containing 'foo' *OR* 'bar'.

You want lines containing *BOTH* 'foo' *AND* 'bar'. Either of these commands will do:

```
sed '/foo/!d;/bar/!d' file.log

awk '/foo/ && /bar/' file.log
```

Both commands -- in theory -- *should* be much more efficient than your `cat | grep | grep` construct because:

- Both `sed` and `awk` perform their own file reading; no need for pipe overhead
- The 'programs' I gave to `sed` and `awk` above use Boolean short-circuiting to quickly skip lines not containing 'foo', thus testing only lines containing 'foo' to the /bar/ regex

However, I haven't tested them. YMMV :)

Comment: Interesting ideas. In the end, two greps wins with 26 seconds to 31 seconds. I know those aren't a ton, but I was curious for the next time I happen to have even larger log files. Accepted for teaching me two other ways to do it.

Comment: @dtbarne `cat|grep|grep` wins? meh, there goes my theory of 'sed/awk should be faster' out of the window :-/

Comment: I don't know about awk, but my experience is that sed is much much slower than it needs to be, while grep is fairly well optimized.

Comment: Both `sed` and `awk` are programming languages and neither is very optimized. You also must remember that the first `grep` might have to parse hundreds of lines, but the second `grep` may only have to parse a dozen lines, so the double grep isn't as inefficient as you might think. Getting rid of the regular expression parser by using `fgrep` can be even more efficient.

Comment: While using a single grep has the advantage of only parsing input once, the regex is not trivial. Two piped greps on the other hand use simpler expressions, which are faster to match. And the second invocation needs to handle less input as David W. pointed out. A different input (e.g. different percentage of matching lines) could give the opposite result. As with any question related to performance, you never really know what is fast until you measure your exact use case - intuitions may be misleading.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, the fastest way should be:

```
grep -E '(foo.*bar|bar.*foo)' file.log
```

For several reasons: First, grep reads directly from the file, rather than adding the step of having cat read it and stuff it down a pipe for grep to read.  Second, it uses only a single instance of grep, so each line of the file only has to be processed once.  Third, `grep -E` is generally faster than plain grep on large files (but slower on small files), although this will depend on your implementation of grep.  Finally, grep (in all its variants) is optimized for string searching, while sed and awk are general-purpose tools that happen to be able to search (but aren't optimized for it).

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally missed that. In fact, I'm not even sure I commented on the answer I meant to comment on. I'll delete my original comment so as not to trip anyone else up!

Answer (score 3):

These two operations are fundamentally different. This one:

```
cat file.log | grep foo | grep bar
```

looks for foo in file.log, then looks for bar in whatever the last grep output. Whereas `cat file.log | grep -E '(foo|bar)'` looks for either foo or bar in file.log. The output should be very different. Use whatever behavior you need.

As for efficiency, they're not really comparable because they do different things. Both should be fast enough, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this:

```
cat file.log | grep foo | grep bar
```

You're only printing lines that contain both `foo` and `bar` in any order. If this is your intention:

```
grep -e "foo.*bar" -e "bar.*foo" file.log
```

Will be more efficient since I only have to parse the output once.

Notice I don't need the `cat` which is more efficient in itself. You rarely ever need `cat` unless you are *concatinating* files (which is the purpose of the command). 99% of the time you can either add a file name to the end of the first command in a pipe, or if you have a command like `tr` that doesn't allow you to use a file, you can always redirect the input like this:

```
tr `a-z` `A-Z` < $fileName
```

But, enough about useless `cat`s. I have two at home.

You can pass multiple regular expressions to a single `grep` which is usually a bit more efficient than piping multiple `greps`. However, if you can eliminate regular expressions, you might find this the most efficient:

```
fgrep "foo" file.log | fgrep "bar"
```

Unlike `grep`, `fgrep` doesn't parse regular expressions which means it can parse lines much, much faster. Try this:

```
time fgrep "foo" file.log | fgrep "bar"
```

and

```
time grep -e "foo.*bar" -e "bar.*foo" file.log
```

And see which is faster.